# <<Notation` raises warnings

Tags: warning-messages, custom-notation

In a completely fresh kernel (after `Quit[]`ing), when I do

```
<<Notation`
```

I am met with

```
Join::incpt: Incompatible elements in Join[<|intt ->RowBox[{\[Integral],
RowBox[{\[SelectionPlaceholder] ,RowBox[{\[DifferentialD],\[Placeholder] }]}]}],
dintt ->RowBox[{SubsuperscriptBox[\[Integral],\[SelectionPlaceholder] ,
\[Placeholder] ],RowBox[{\[Placeholder] ,RowBox[{\[DifferentialD],\[Placeholder] }]}]}],
rintt ->RowBox[{UnderscriptBox[\[Integral],RowBox[{\[SelectionPlaceholder] ,
\[Element],\[Placeholder] }]],\[Placeholder] }],<<42>>,
cS ->TemplateBox[{},CombinatorS ],cW ->TemplateBox[{},CombinatorW ],
cY ->TemplateBox[{},CombinatorY ]|>,{<<1>>},{<<1>>},<<5>>,{<<1>>},{<<1>>},<<3>>] 
cannot be joined.
```

And another similarly dense error message; both are shown in the image below.

[image: warnings]

Of course, `Join::incpt` doesn't link to anything in the documentation, and it's not clear at all what this warning/error means.

Questions:

- Since it's in the `Notation` package, I think this is Wolfram's problem?
- Does it happen for others?

In case it matters, I am using `$Version == "12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)"`.  I don't think this happened with recent previous versions.

If so:

- Is it a bug?
- Can you find an example expression that *looks* like it is correct notation but fails because of this warning?

If not (since @Rohit Namjoshi is unable to reproduce on the same version):

- What might I have done to my installation that caused this?

Comment: Unable to reproduce on "12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)".

Comment: Hmmm THAT is odd.

Comment: I'm seeing exactly the same `Join: Incompatible elements ....` error with 12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021) under macOS Big Sur 11.4.

Comment: I'm also on Big Sur 11.4 [macOS 11.4 (20F71)]; on a Intel chip.  @RohitNamjoshi are you on 11.4?  Intel chip or apple silicon?

Comment: Can confirm that this also happens on 12.3 for Windows 10

Comment: @evanb on Intel - 2.9 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i9 and Big Sur 11.2.2 (20D80).

Answer (score 7):

It looks like they changed `InputAliases` from a list to an association, but this doesn't seem to be properly documented as far as I can tell. And clearly, they also did not update the `` Notation` ``  package to support the new syntax. Until they fix it, you can use the following code to load the `` Notation` ``  package without any errors:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[
 {SetDelayed},
 Unprotect@SetDelayed;
 HoldPattern[
   Notation`AddInputAlias[args___] := 
    With[v : {s_ = _, o_ = _}, 
     With[_, SetOptions[n_, InputAliases -> Join[_, _]]]]] :=
  (
   Notation`AddInputAlias[args] := 
    With[v, SetOptions[n, InputAliases -> Join[o, <|s|>]]]
   );
 << Notation`
 ]
```

This effectively fixes the two offending definitions of `AddInputAlias` such that they work properly with the new format.

You might also need to reset the value of `InputAliases` to the state before `` Notation` ``  broke it:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, InputAliases -> 
  FirstCase[
    Quiet@CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, InputAliases], 
    _Association,
    Inherited,
    All
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is resolved in version 13.0 (at least on `$Version == "13.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"`).

Comment: Currently, it fails in Wolfram Cloud 13.0.1 for Linux x86 64-bit and Wolfram Engine Kernel 13.0.0 Windows

Comment: Hm.  I will un-accept my self-answer.  Please let me know when it is resolved!  You should consider submitting a bug report to Wolfram support.